# How to generate Entity Framework Objects from script

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on a entity framework project generating the Entity classes using the New-> ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> Code First From Database. I then select nearly 100 tables to generate (not all tables are suitable to go in the model).

Problem is I am regularly updating the schema, and the only way to refresh the model seems to be to delete and start again, which is fine except I have to re-select the nearly 100 tables again.

Is there any easy way of scripting this generation process?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [Entity Framework Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) and start doing your schema changes from the code itself

Comment: Thanks but not possible in our case as the application is deployed to customers and we need to script and control the migration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the CompanyName.ProjectName.Infrastructure.EfRepository (the project which has your DbContext) as start up project of the solution
2. Open the Package manager console
3. Choose CompanyName.ProjectName.Infrastructure.EfRepository as default project
4. Run the following commands:
   Enable-Migrations -ConnectionStringName "EfDataRepository"
   Add-Migration Initial -ConnectionStringName "EfDataRepository"
   Update-Database -ConnectionStringName "EfDataRepository" -Script -SourceMigration:0
5. Then delete the auto-generated Migrations folder within the EF project!

Where `EfDataRepository` is the connection string name.